# Prove that injection of 0 or 1 in strings of regular lang > regular lang

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let $Σ = \{0, 1\}$. For a language $L$ over $Σ$, consider the language $$\text{INS}(L) = \{u0v \mid uv \in L\} \cup \{u1v \mid uv ∈ L\}.$$ 
For example, if $L = \{1, 01, 0010\}$ then $\text{INS}(L)$ contains, for example $01010$, which can be obtained using $u = 0$ and $v = 010$, and so on. 
Show that if $L$ is a regular language then $\text{INS}(L)$ is also regular.

I've been stuck on this for quite a while.

Comment: Are you familiar with NFAs and $\epsilon$-transitions? They might be useful. Also, think about how you might modify the proof that $L^2 = \{uv | uv \in L \}$ is regular when $L$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If you have an automaton that accepts $L$, how would you make one that accepts INS(L)?

Comment: @saulspatz this is what I'm trying to find

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes I am familiar with them, however I couldn't construct an NFA that would accepts INS(L)

Comment: Suppose you get to a final state of the original automaton (the one accepting L)?  What else has to happen for you to get to a final state of the desired automaton that recognizes INS(L)?

Comment: @saulspatz The thing is that the 0 or 1 could be injected in string in L anywhere, therefore with the new injection I might not even reach in final state. What else has to happen is that I need to somehow consume the 0 (or 1) without modifying the rest of the transitions

Comment: Try two copies of the automaton in tandem (one after the other).

Comment: The first copy of the automaton would consume the string though wouldn't it? Also the 0 and 1 are not injected at the end of the string in L (u and v don't have to belong to L but uv does) so given the modified string yo might not even reach the finishing state in the first copy of the automaton of L

Comment: Your example is incorrect: $0010$ is not in $\text{INS}(L)$: it should be $u0v = 00010$ or $u1v = 01010$ instead.

Comment: Yes sorry I've fixed the example my bad

Answer (score 0):

Well, take an accepting automaton A for the language $L$.

Then the accepting automaton $A'$ for the language $L'=INS(L)$ is given as follows:

1) Take the automaton $A$ and the starting state of $A$ is the starting state of $A'$.

2) Take the ending states of $A$ in $A'$ and extend the ending states by the transitions $\stackrel{0}{\rightarrow}$ and $\stackrel{1}{\rightarrow}$ and connect them to the starting state of another copy of $A$.

3) The ending states of the second copy of $A$ are the ending states of $A'$.

So the automaton $A'$ looks as follows

$$\rightarrow A \stackrel{0/1}{\rightarrow} A.$$

Comment: In that case wouldn't the first automaton consume the string? The string would end before u reach the automaton number 2. What you did would prove L1L and L0L but not u1v and u0v where uv is in L since in my case the 1 (or 0) is injected at any place in any string inside of L. And you can't assume that u is in L and v is in L (Since we only have uv given to be in L)